# Draw transparent colour - p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Is it possible to draw with transparency like you would draw with any colour?

For example if i'm using a `createGraphics()` you can use `clear()` to make the canvas transparent, but what if I wanted to draw a black background with a see-through hole in the middle (draw a "transparent filled" ellipse that cuts through?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could play around with the `blendMode()` function. [Here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/blendMode) is the reference for the `blendMode()` function.

Or you could call the `set()` function on each pixel. [Here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/set) is the reference for the `set()` function.

Or you could look into using an **image mask**. For example, you could create an image with a transparent center ahead of time, and then display that over top your sketch.

Another option is to use the `mask()` function. [Here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/mask) is the reference for the `mask()` function.